# Usage of would for conditional with only result-clause

Tags: grammar

In all the resources that I have seen, I always find that would for conditional 2 and 3 is made up of a sentence with if-clause (or similar) and result clause (would).

But then I find many phrases like this:
*Nobody in their right mind would put that person on the witness stand*

Is it just a type of conditional 2, but without if-clause? This makes sense in the Spanish translation, but I don't know.
I have not found any resources where I explain this form of the conditional

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The "if" clause ***is*** the condition, so if there's no "if" clause, then it's not a conditional at all.

Your example sentence uses "would" to create an *unreal mood* in exactly the same way unreal conditionals like 2nd and 3rd conditional do, but *not everything that's unreal is a conditional*.